# When minifying javascript, //@ sourceUrl is removed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, minify, uglifyjs

I load my javascript files dinamically, so when I load them,  to see  those files in DevTools, I use the sourceUrl directive like this

```
//@ sourceURL=foo.js
```

I now added to my project [UglifyJS2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) to minify my JS, but the problem is that its considering the sourceUrl directive as a comment.

So now its removing that and I can't see my scripts in dev tools.

Is there a way I can avoid this happening ?

Comment: Are you using UglifyJS or UglifyJS2?