# How to map client-side code to Source Code

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, source-maps

Recently I learned that it's possible to show JavaScript code added to the DOM / Dev Tools Elements tab by using `document.write`, `eval`, etc. to the Source panel of Chrome Dev Tools and other browsers. This is done by adding a comment before the closing `<script>`:

```
<script>
...

//# sourceURL=filename.js
</script>
```

I tried to apply this but the comment is not added by the HtmlService to browser. How can the Google Apps Script client-side code be shown in the Dev Tools Sources panel?

Below is my attempt of adding  `sourceURL` as shown above
Code.gs

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput()
    .append(`
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  <form>
  <input type="text" name="something" value="default value"><br>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <script>
  function formSubmitHandler(){
    google.script.run.doSomething(event.currentTarget)
  }
  //# sourceURL=javascript.js
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
`)
    .setTitle('Demo')
    .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1');
}

function doSomething(formData){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(formData.something));
}
```

Related

- [How to go about debugging JavaScript in the HtmlService in Google Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26518902/1595451). Not a duplicate because the OP didn't included a MCVE, doesn't mention how the `HtmlOutput` was created. The most common case is to use `HtmlService.createHtmlOutpuFromFile(filename)` but in this case I'm using `HtmlService.createHtmlOutput().append(string)`.
- [When minifying javascript, //@ sourceUrl is removed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27934624/1595451). Not a duplicate because in Google Apps Script HtmlService do not minimize the code.
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/13129905/1595451. Not a duplicate because the JavaScript code is added using jQuery and in this case the code is added by using the Google Apps Script HtmlService

References

- [Map Preprocessed Code to Source Code](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/source-maps/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of adding the whole client-side code at once (using a single `HtmlOutput.append` ), split the code in at least two parts. The first one should include the code from the top to the first `/` of `//# sourceURL=javascript.js`, the second part should add the rest of the code. The key here is to avoid having `//` added at the same time (instead of using a single `HtmlOutput.append` use two).

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput()
    .append(`
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  <form>
  <input type="text" name="something" value="default value"><br>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <script>
  function formSubmitHandler(){
    google.script.run.doSomething(event.currentTarget)
  }
  /`)
  .append(`/# sourceURL=javascript.js
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
`)
    .setTitle('Demo')
    .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1');
}

function doSomething(formData){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(formData.something));
}
```

I also tried this in a prototype SPA using templated HTML with multiple files pulled from multiple libraries (each library has one or two sets of three .html files, index, css and js, each seat corresponds to module having at least one form and one list view. The final `HtmlOutput` has > 20 `<stript>`, all are mapped correctly to Source Code.

The JavaScript code mapped to Source Code will appear as show in the following image:

[image]

Right clicking the file name and selecting `Copy link address` will return something like this:

```
https://n-hyluq5mztdwi5brxcufwcb4wfggugjbof23qiby-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/javascript.js
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your current issue, about `I was not able to upload an image showing client-side JavaScript in Source Code.`, is this thread useful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/61692427 If this was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Hi Tanaike .. the note is about uploading the image to this answer to show how the client-side code looks in Chrome Source Code

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understood it. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: @Tanaike No need to feel sorry / apologize. Appreciate your continued support as always.

Comment: Hi @TheDeadMan. Before going to your post, what do you think about this question and answer? Are they clear? Do you find them helpful?

Comment: @Rubén  very useful, that using this structure it works as expected

Comment: How would this apply with .createHtmlOutputFromFile() ?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was trying to get this to work in the context of AppsScript running from a Google Sheet extension, producing a custom dialog. Unfortunately, while your hack to getting the `//# sourceURL=filename.js` pragma comment into the `HtmlOutput` worked, there was still something else downstream stripping all the comments.

So I had to work around it by returning output that was a simple script to add a script element with the generated code, plus the pragma comment, into the DOM at runtime. Even more hacky, but without this, it's impossible to debug...

**Edited/Added:**

Here's the essence of what I had to do in order to go from a JavaScript module in my repo (`.js` containing utility functions, for example) to the same file in DevTools loaded as a result of opening a custom dialog given an HTML template in GAS.

I start with a module `util.js`:

```js
// a comment to preserve
const sayHello = () => console.log('hello');

window.myApp = { sayHello };
```

1. Run this through a [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/) IIFE build. The output is `util.js.html` (`.html` because that's what `clasp` will sync and what you can load as a template).

Using Rollup is key because it doesn't mangle its output like Webpack does into a single-line `eval()` statement that absolutely requires a source map to read. So the code it produces is code largely as you wrote it, but perhaps transpiled to hit an ES target you set, or even convert JSX into JS (or TypeScript into JS).

The result is a self-executing script:

```js
(function () {
'use strict';

// a comment to preserve
const sayHello = () => console.log('hello');

window.myApp = { sayHello };

})();
```

2. Create a GAS function called `includeScript`.
3. In your dialog's HTML template file, include your generated script using the function:

```html
<?!= includeScript('path/to/generated/util.js.html') />
```

The `includeScript()` function is where all the magic happens.

1. Load the script template file's content while preserving comments:

```js
  // we basically use this just to be able to load the raw file from the cloud-based file system
  // NOTE: crucially, this retains comments
  // NOTE: we have to wrap in a <script> block to make sure that the HtmlOutput's content, which
  //  we get later on, will NOT XML-encode the string, which would mess-up things like less-than
  //  operators ('<' would become '&lt;'); by putting the raw content in a <script> block, its
  //  treated as CDATA instead of HTML code that needs to be escaped
  const rawContent = `<script>${HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(
    'path/to/generated/util.js.html'
  ).getRawContent()}</script>`;
  const template = HtmlService.createTemplate(rawContent);
```

Note that this is the point where you could apply a scope to the `template` prior to evaluating it, if you wanted/needed to.

2. Get the actual code out the script (still with comments so far):

```js
  const output = template.evaluate();

  // unwrap the now-evaluated raw content from the temporary <script> block because we're now
  //  going to put the code _into_ an actual <script> element in the DOM (when the generated
  //  output runs in the browser)
  let code = output
    .getContent()
    .replace(/^<script>/gm, '')
    .replace(/<\/script>$/gm, '');
```

Note that the technique suggested in this post (above) must only work for Google Web Services, not GAS, because comments are still stripped. So now we have to do something really hacky in order to get the raw code we now have in `code` while preserving comments.

First, add the pragma comment to the source that identifies its original module structure/path/directory so that you can find this file in DevTools once it loads:

```js
code = `${code}\n//# sourceURL=path/to/original/util.js`;
```

Finally, return the actual string that the `HtmlService` will use in the HTML file it's loading. Remember, the `includeScript()` function is executing in the template you're giving to `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(...)`:

```html
<?!= includeScript('path/to/generated/util.js.html') />
```

What we need to do is URI-encode (to preserve extended characters in your strings), and Base64-encode to preserve quotes and such that would otherwise get converted into HTML characters like `&quot;`, the `code` so that we end-up with a string that the `HtmlService` essentially won't touch (i.e. strip comments, including that `sourceURL` pragma critical to debugging in DevTools).

And because the browser won't load this on its own, we need to wrap that blob into a little loader function that will undo these encodings in the browser:

```js
    return `<script>
(function () {
  const code = decodeURIComponent(atob('${Utilities.base64Encode(
    encodeURIComponent(code)
  )}'));
  const scriptEl = document.createElement('script');
  scriptEl.textContent = code;
  document.body.appendChild(scriptEl);
})();
</script>`;
```

That's for the "dev" version of your code. The "prod" version doesn't need to do all this because presumably, you don't need comments in your prod version, and you probably also minify it anyway.

So for "prod", this is all you need instead of the self-executing function that unwraps the encoding (because you don't need to encode the `code` in the first place since you don't need to preserve anything):

```js
return `<script>${code}</script>`;
```

And I do have Dev and Prod builds of each of my JS and JSX modules, through Rollup. My Dev builds preserve comments and don't minify, while my Prod builds strip comments and minify.

Hopefully this helps... It's too much code in too many files to just post here. I should really OSS my GAS build solution, but that's for another time.

Comment: Hey, can you post the code you used, I'm trying to do a similar thing.

Comment: @JordanBiserkov I added some details to my original answer. Hopefully it helps you out!